# Google map in Angular JS: Event listener in a marker doesn't redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a small problem when trying to attach an event listener to a Google Maps Marker that redirects to a different route using angular.

My code is similar to [this Google example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure), and here's how I define my listener into an AngularJS controller:

```
        marker.branchId = 35;

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            $location.path('/showbranch/' + this.branchId);
        });
        markers.push(marker);
```

On the chrome debugger I can see that the $location object is there (it's not null nor undefined) and that the ID I need is the right one too. No error message is shown on the console after clicking on a marker, but the redirection is not effective right after clicking on a marker.

However, if I click on a marker AND AFTER THAT, I click on any other button of the page, then the routing is performed (that is, then I am redirected to the route I was looking for when clicking on the marker). It seems to be some sort of scope problem, but I don't find the solution. Does anyone have a hint?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.location.href = '/showbranch/' + this.branchId;

Tried this?

Comment: Yes, thanks!!! In fact, window.location.href = '#/showbranch/' + this.branchId; does the trick :))) I wonder why the $location service doesn't work... Vanilla is our friend ;)

Comment: You should not do that, keep it within Angular. Just be aware that the event is fired from outside angular, therefore you need to tell angular about the change.  
`$scope.$apply(function(){
        $location.path('/showbranch/'+this.branchId;
});`